# Removing reverse versions of lists from a nested list

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

I need to remove the reverse versions of lists from list of lists. I.e.: `{{1,2},{2,2},{2,1},{a,1,2},{2,1,a}}` I need to reduce to `{{1,2},{2,2},{a,1,2}}`.
The requirement to remove only the reverse of a given list means that permutations other than the reverse will be conserved, so that

```
{{1,2,3},{2,1,3},{3,2,1},{1,2,2},{a,1,2},{2,1,a}}
```

should reduce to

```
{{1,2,3},{2,1,3},{1,2,2},{a,1,2}}
```

My try gives correct result but it use nested `For` which is not too nice. Does anyone know of a better way to do it?

Comment: Do you need to conserve the ordering in the sublists order? If not, you could map Sort on each one of them and then use Union to remove duplicates. As in `Union[Sort /@ {{1, 2}, {2, 2}, {2, 1}, {a, 1, 2}}]`

Comment: @Peltio It's not so easy, `{{1,2,3}, {3,1,2}}` should not be reduced and it will be with your method.

Comment: @Kuba But the basic idea is sane: find a canonical for for sublists, then use `Union` for an efficient solution.  The question is: what efficiently computable canonical form can we use? (I.e. a way to unambiguously choose either `list` or `Reverse[list]` for each item.)

Comment: @Szabolcs I can agree with you but Peltio's comment is not describing an idea which has to be improved, but the solution which fits only by a coincidence. Or I've missed something again? :)

Comment: @Kuba, you're right, I did not consider other permutations.

Comment: @Szabolcs If the duplicates of lists themselves should also be deleted, then Kuba's solution is the way to go. If not, then the problem is in principle unsolvable in the single-list canonical form approach, since one has to keep the memory if which version was encountered first (as I did in mine) - which is, it can not be reduced to just per-element canonical form computations.

Comment: @Artes You was the first, but as you wish..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All right, this will be a linear-time solution:

```
ClearAll[removeReversed];
removeReversed[l_List] :=
   Module[{f},
     f[x_List] := (f[Reverse[x]] = Sequence[]; x);
     f /@ l]
```

For example:

```
lst = {{1, 2}, {2, 2}, {2, 1}, {a, 1, 2}, {2, 1, a}};
```

then:

```
removeReversed @ lst

(* {{1, 2}, {2, 2}, {a, 1, 2}} *)
```

Comment: Actually, this is not quite right...

Comment: Try this list {{0,0,0,0,0,0}, {1,1,0,0,0,0}, {1,1,1,1,0,0}, {1,1,1,1,1,1}, {1,1,0,1,1,0}, {1,1,0,0,1,1}, {0,1,1,0,0,0}, {0,1,1,1,1,0}, {0,1,1,0,1,1}, {0,0,1,1,0,0}, {0,0,1,1,1,1}, {0,0,0,1,1,0}, {0,0,0,0,1,1}}. Artes' solutions works butter

Comment: I was thinking about deleting the same elements with my method. I'm almost sure it must be done. Otherwise the filtering depends of main list order. For example: try `removeReversed` at `lst = {{1, 2}, {1, 2}, {2, 1}};` and at `Reverse[lst]`.

Comment: @Kuba Yes, surely it depends on main list order. Why should it not? These are just different problems. In the way the problem is specified now, it does not assume removal of duplicate lists.

Comment: Well, it's natural for me it shouldn't unless specified explicitly. Unfortunatelly OP's example does not have this feature so we have to wait to check if you are right. But yes, there is no good reason why it shouldn't.

Comment: @Kuba All right, I did not retract my vote for your answer anyway :)

Comment: @LeonidShifrin This is an instance where a good answer is not well appreciated. Wanted to delete my answer but I think it should rest for educational purposes. Perhaps I should add some benchmarks, but I find this question not quite well focused.

Comment: @Artes Thanks man, but I think this is the case when the answer gets appreciation slowly, in part because it takes more effort to get the context of both the question, and the answer (than in some other questions like e.g. [this one](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/35261/how-do-i-define-an-argument-pattern-for-a-head-of-not-a-given-value/)). Besides, there still might be better ones. Re: your answer - you should definitely keep it, in particular for educational purposes (as you mentioned), I think.

Comment: @ФилиппЦветков Thanks for the accept. But what made you change your mind?

Comment: @LeonidShifrin "I'd accept Leonid's answer, since it is fast and works better for long lists. – Artes 15 hours ago"

Comment: @ФилиппЦветков Ok, I see. Artes is generous as always.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin `f[x_List] := (f[Reverse[x]] = Sequence[]; x);` I've never seen this kind of definition before. What is this?

Comment: @matheorem This is a special case of memoization. You can search for "memoization" on this site. Basically, this means that every call to `f` on a reverse list will result in `Sequence[]`, effectively deleting it.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin I understand. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

```
list = {{1, 2}, {2, 2}, {2, 1}, {a, 1, 2}, {2, 1, a}};
```

There is an optional `test` argument in `DeleteDuplicates`:

```
DeleteDuplicates[ list, Reverse[#1] == #2 &]
```

> ```
> {{1, 2}, {2, 2}, {a, 1, 2}}
> ```

alternatively we can use `SameTest` in `Union`:

```
Union[ list, SameTest -> (Reverse[#1] == #2 &)]
```

Comment: This is what came to my mind first, too. Alas, it will have quadratic complexity for large lists, because `DeleteDuplicates` will have to perform pairwise comparisons.

Answer (score 2):

```
GatherBy[list, Sort[{#, Reverse@#}] &][[;; , 1]]
```

I've deleted this answer because of Leonid's remark but now I think exact duplicates needs to be deleted to, otherwise the filtering depends of the order in main list.

Let's see that with Artes' solution:

```
list = {{1, 2}, {1, 2}, {2, 1}};
DeleteDuplicates[list, Reverse[#1] == #2 &]
DeleteDuplicates[Reverse@list, Reverse[#1] == #2 &]
```

> ```
> {{1, 2}, {1, 2}}
> {{2, 1}}
> ```

Comment: Actually, I was too fast to vote. This also removes the same lists occurring later on, not just their reverse versions.

Answer (score 0):

Another work around can be having a new list every time with reversed element removed.

```
   fun[l_List] := 
     Block[{k = l, 
       fin}, {fin = Quiet[Last[Table[If[MemberQ[k, Reverse[k[[i]]]] && 
             Hash[k[[i]]] != Hash[Reverse[k[[i]]]], 
             k = DeleteCases[k, Reverse[k[[i]]]], k], {i, 1, 
             Length[k]}]]]}; fin]


{{1,2,3},{2,1,3},{3,2,1},{1,2,2},{a,1,2},{2,1,a}}
```

> {{1, 2, 3}, {2, 1, 3}, {1, 2, 2}, {a, 1, 2}}

```
{{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1,
    1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
   0}, {0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0}, {0,
    0, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1}}
```

> {{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1,
>      1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
>     0}, {0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0}}

```
 {{1, 2}, {2, 2}, {2, 1}, {a, 1, 2}, {2, 1, a}}
```

> {{1, 2}, {2, 2}, {a, 1, 2}}

Answer (score 0):

Just a variant (suffering from pairwise comparison growth):

```
fun[u_List]:=Tally[Union[u],#1===Reverse@#2&][[;;,1]]
```

Test lists:

```
list1={{1,2,3},{2,1,3},{3,2,1},{1,2,2},{a,1,2},{2,1,a}}
list2={{1, 2}, {1, 2}, {2, 1}}
```

Applying:

```
fun[list1]
fun[list2]
```

yields:

{{1, 2, 2}, {1, 2, 3}, {2, 1, 3}, {2, 1, a}}

{{1,2}}

To avoid double pairwise comparisons (Union, then Tally):

```
func[u_]:=Tally[u,#1===#2||#1===Reverse@#2&][[;;,1]]
```