# How to delete mirror symmetric point pair efficiently

Tags: list-manipulation

Look at following pic

[image]

There are five points, I can generate the following point pairs

```
In:= tt=Subsets[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {2}]

Out:= {{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}, {1, 5}, {2, 3}, {2, 4}, {2, 5}, {3, 
  4}, {3, 5}, {4, 5}}
```

But if I define mirror symmetry equivalence between point pairs. For example

{1,2} equals {4,5}
{1,3} equals {3,5}
{1,4} equals {2,5}
{2,3} equals {3,4}
.....etc

Then how to select half of the symmetric point pair from tt and keep only half of the original set. And in this case, I want keep left part, That is keep

{{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}, {1, 5}, {2, 3}, {2, 4}}

Comment: The title seems a little misleading:  Are you interested in **deleting** symmetric pairs from an arbitrary list, or just **generating** a list of all pairs `{i, j}` with `i < j && i+ j <= n + 1` (where `n` is `5` in the example above)?  It seems the latter from the comments.

Comment: @MichaelE2 You're right. But anyway, the answers contain methods tackle both general case and specific case.

Answer (score 6):

Let's start with standard approaches which have quadratic time complexity, so for larger lists they are not recommended:

```
Union[ tt, SameTest -> (#1 == {6, 6} - Reverse @ #2 &)] 

DeleteDuplicates[ tt, #1 == {6, 6} - Reverse @ #2 &]
```

they both return:

> ```
> {{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}, {1, 5}, {2, 3}, {2, 4}}
> ```

Alternatively let's use another approach (I learnt it from this [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/35604/removing-reverse-versions-of-lists-from-a-nested-list/35608#35608) by Leonid Shifrin):

```
deleteMS[n_?OddQ] /; n > 2 := 
  Module[{ lst = Subsets[Range[n], {2}], g}, 
           g[x_] := (g[{n + 1, n + 1} - Reverse@x] = Sequence[]; x);
           g /@ lst]
```

now

```
deleteMS[5]
```

> ```
> {{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}, {1, 5}, {2, 3}, {2, 4}}
> ```

and for example

```
deleteMS[1351] // Length
```

> ```
> 456300
> ```

I would apply `deleteMS` for larger `n` since its time complexity is linear unlike in the former approaches. One can test that for `n > 100` it works reasonably fast, while `DeleteDuplicates` or `Union` with tests are very inefficient.

Comment: In my system: `Timing[Length[deleteMS[1351]]]` gives `{5.584836, 456300}` and `Timing[Length[getMeTheSymms[1351]]]` gives `{1.528810, 456300}`.

Comment: why `deleteMS` didn't give any result on my mathematica?

Comment: Oh, I know, n must be odd

Answer (score 4):

For each pair, generate the symmetric pairs, put them in some canonical order and then delete the repeated cases.

```
getMeTheSymms[n_Integer?Positive] := Map[First, Union[Sort[{#, Sort[n + 1 - #]}] & /@ 
  Subsets[Range[n], {2}]], {1}];
getMeTheSymms[5]
(*{{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}, {1, 5}, {2, 3}, {2, 4}}*)
```

---

If you are constrained by time, you might want to use the following code:

```
fasterSymms[n_Integer?Positive] := Flatten[
  Table[{i, j}, {i, 1, n/2}, {j, i + 1, n - i + 1}], 1]
```

Comment: clever for `getMeTheSymms`! Straight and fast for `fasterSymms`

Comment: @matheorem: Yep, I think you cannot beat `fasterSymm`. In my system, `Timing[Length[fasterSymms[1351]]]` gives `{0.234002, 456300}`.

Comment: what does the n/2 do?

Comment: It limits the initial cases. Note that the first entry in the elements in the answer is never larger than `n/2` (it is either 1 or 2 in the OP example). So, do not generate extra cases at the beginning.

Answer (score 4):

`Join@@Table[Thread@{i,Range[i+1,n+1-i]},{i,n/2}]` is faster than `HectorSymms` on my system -- 1.29 sec vs 1.66 sec for `n` = 3579. `Join@@(...)` is faster than `Flatten[...,1]`, and adding 1 to the `Range` limits instead adding it to the whole list also saves a little time.

Comment: And this is what I like about MSE .. I knew that "you cannot beat" will attract more interest. Upvoted your answer.

Comment: @RayKoopman  Dankjewel! I will use Join in the future.

Comment: @Kenny These things can be release- and platform-dependent. Try them on your system -- YMMV.

Answer (score 3):

Hector can beat his own code with:

```
HectorSymms[n_Integer?Positive]:=Flatten[Table[Thread[{i,Range[i,n-i]+1}],{i,1,n/2}],1]
```

On my system, the timing for`fasterSymms[1351]`is 0.233s, while`HectorSymms[1351]`takes only 0.098s.

Comment: I had never seen that usage of `Thread` to create nested lists. Upvoted.