# Non-descending Tuples

Tags: list-manipulation, combinatorics

I want to get all the non-descending tuples of a list with given length, for example:

```
f[{1,2,3,4},{3}]
```

> ```
> {{1,1,1},{1,1,2},{1,1,3},{1,1,4},{1,2,2},{1,2,3},{1,2,4},{1,3,3},{1,3,4},{1,4,4},
>  {2,2,2},……,{4,4,4}}
> ```

A function lies between `Tuples` and `Subsets` to some degree.

Is the an efficient way to achieve this? (It should be general for all kind of elements, like `Tuples`, not specifically for `Integers`.)

Comment: [related](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4319222/499167) question on StackOverflow where [High Performance Mark](http://stackoverflow.com/users/44309/high-performance-mark) gives a [nice answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4319896/499167)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to delete mirror symmetric point pair efficiently](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/37405/how-to-delete-mirror-symmetric-point-pair-efficiently)

Comment: Related [equivalent-nested-loop-structure](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/35560/equivalent-nested-loop-structure)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A general solution for your problem should not create all tuples, only to throw most of them away. Additionally, one should consider the situation when the elements in the list cannot be compared, but the *user* knows that they are ordered. Therefore, here is an approach which creates the positions rather the elements itself.

When we create all tuples and highlight the elements for your specific example, we notice a pattern:

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Staring at this a while, you might notice that you can solve this with a nested `Table`

```
Table[{i, j, k}, {i, 4}, {j, i, 4}, {k, j, 4}]

(* {{{{1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 2}, {1, 1, 3}, {1, 1, 4}}, {{1, 2, 
    2}, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 4}}, {{1, 3, 3}, {1, 3, 4}}, {{1, 4, 
    4}}}, {{{2, 2, 2}, {2, 2, 3}, {2, 2, 4}}, {{2, 3, 3}, {2, 3, 
    4}}, {{2, 4, 4}}}, {{{3, 3, 3}, {3, 3, 4}}, {{3, 4, 4}}}, {{{4, 4, 4}}}} *)
```

If you look closer at the iterators i,j, and k you see how it works: You need 3 iterators because you want tuples of length 3 and you need to iterate to 4, because your list has length 4. If you now take the above outcome as positions in a list, you can create the result for a general (uncomparable) list:

```
Table[Part[{a, b, c, d}, {i, j, k}], {i, 4}, {j, i, 4}, {k, j, 4}]

(* {{{{a, a, a}, {a, a, b}, {a, a, c}, {a, a, d}}, {{a, b, 
    b}, {a, b, c}, {a, b, d}}, {{a, c, c}, {a, c, d}}, {{a, d, 
    d}}}, {{{b, b, b}, {b, b, c}, {b, b, d}}, {{b, c, c}, {b, c, 
    d}}, {{b, d, d}}}, {{{c, c, c}, {c, c, d}}, {{c, d, d}}}, {{{d, d, d}}}} *)
```

What's left is to do is to flatten the result appropriately and to create this `Table` dynamically for any list and any tuple-length:

```
f[l_List, n_] := 
 With[{iter = {#2, #1, Length[l]} & @@@ 
     Partition[Prepend[Array[Unique[] &, n], 1], 2, 1]},
  Part[l, #] & /@ 
   Flatten[Table @@ {iter[[All, 1]], Sequence @@ iter}, n - 1]
]
```

And now you can use the approach for any kind of list. Be careful, you have to ensure that the input list is sorted to your needs:

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Sorry to resurrect this rather old post, I have found this code very useful and makes my current project viable (it wasn't when I was simply generating the tuples and then deleting the ones that I didn't need). Is there a way to speed this up through parallelisation?

Answer (score 2):

Sometime ago I posted a similar function (search `comb`) at

[Shuffle product of two lists](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/41614/shuffle-product-of-two-lists/41674#41674)

I copy and paste the function here. This function generates increasing number tuples. The idea is to first generate an expression like `Table[{i[1],i[2], ...},{i[1],0,m}, {i[2], i[1], m}, ...]`, and then execute this expression.

```
comb[lenIn_, lenOut_] := Module[{i}, i[0] = 0;
  Flatten[#, lenOut - 1] &@
   With[{elem = i@# & /@ Range@lenOut, 
     ranges = Sequence @@ ({i[#], i[# - 1], lenIn - 1} & /@ Range@lenOut)}, 
    Table[elem, ranges]]]
```

For example,

```
comb[4, 3]
```

> {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 2}, {0, 0, 3}, {0, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 2}, {0,
>          1, 3}, {0, 2, 2}, {0, 2, 3}, {0, 3, 3}, {1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 2}, {1, 
>         1, 3}, {1, 2, 2}, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 3, 3}, {2, 2, 2}, {2, 2, 3}, {2, 3,
>          3}, {3, 3, 3}}

To better fit your question, one can write a helper function

```
f[lst_, n_] := 
 Extract[Sort@lst, #] & /@ Map[{#} &, comb[Length@lst, n] + 1, {-1}]
```

For example,

```
f[{a, b, c}, 2]
```

> {{a, a}, {a, b}, {a, c}, {b, b}, {b, c}, {c, c}}

EDIT: @halirutan has already posted an answer, with essentially the same algorithm. Sorry for my duplicate answer! But let me keep it from being deleted because of some minor difference between our solutions.

Answer (score 1):

`Select[Tuples[{1, 2, 3, 4}, 3], OrderedQ ]` will do it...

Or generalized to take arguments `Select[Tuples[#1, #2], OrderedQ] &[{1, 2, 3, 4}, 3]`