# How to group each element with each consecutive elements in one head

Tags: list-manipulation

Suppose I have the following list:

```
list = {a, b, c, d}
```

I want to generate this result:

```
{{f[a, a], f[a, b], f[a, c], f[a, d]}, {f[b, b], f[b, c],
  f[b, d]}, {f[c, c], f[c, d]}, {f[d, d]}}
```

What could be the shortest way?

The list elements can be anything and not necessarily sorted.

Comment: Very nice question, but I assume (because of your previous contributions) that you already have an answer (maybe not the shortest). If not, please excuse :)

Comment: @eldo yes I have an answer but as you said it is not short.

Comment: Closely related: [(9537)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9537), [(42278)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/42278)

Comment: Please see my updated answer.  I argue against your choice of answer.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I argue for Algohi's choice of answer. Why do you complain? In your opinion it's a "I cant't find it" duplicate anyway :)

Comment: @eldo (1) halirutan's method is not the shortest, yet the question clearly asks for *the shortest way.*  "Moving the goalposts" is generally discouraged here.  (2) You will note that I removed my "duplicate" comment and replaced it with a related link.  (3) Even as a moderator I am free to voice my opinion, which is all I have done.  This is not the first time that I have argued for or against a particular choice.  For example [(7687)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/7687) was really an extended comment arguing the superiority of kguler's answer.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard (1) Even now I can read: "I'm still looking for the original question of which I believe this is duplicate." (2) "Even as a moderator I am free to voice my opinion, which is all that I have done." I agree. (3) "Shortness" (an ugly mathematical or philosophical notion btw) is not only a matter of counting characters or seconds, but to find an elegant and understandable algorithm. (4) The accepted  answer tersely demonstrates why `Table` should be part of the language.

Comment: @eldo I forgot that line in my answer; I have removed it.  I agree that shortness might be measured other than character count, but the `LeafCount` of my function is 18, whereas the `LeafCount` of halirutan's code (as an equivalent function) is 24; mine is clearly the simpler code.  In any case I never meant to be antagonistic but only make an intellectual case for a position.  Let's let the matter rest.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

How about a simple table?

```
Table[f @@ list[[{i, j}]], {i, 4}, {j, i, 4}]
```

If you want to use this for a general list, you should use `Length[list]` in the table iterators or maybe:

```
With[{n = Length[list]},
 Table[f @@ list[[{i, j}]], {i, n}, {j, i, n}]
]
```

Comment: Long live Fortran?

Comment: @haliturutan About to upvote, but couldn't you replace the static `4` with `Length@list` ???

Comment: Your table is prettier than mine.

Comment: @eldo Hehe, *haliturutan* sounds a bit like Truthahn in German :-) I edited the answer.

Comment: @alancalvitti Nope, I never used Fortran. Seems to be some other influence.

Answer (score 9):

## Solutions

---

```
Pick[
 Outer[f, list, list],
 UpperTriangularize@ConstantArray[True, {#, #} &@Length@list]
 ]
```

Using the new `Composition` shorthand:

```
Thread@*f @@@ MapIndexed[{#, list[[First@#2 ;;]]} &, list]
```

## Timings

---

Testing with

```
list = Range[1000];
```

the first method takes 0.363 seconds to complete and the second takes 0.120 to complete. As a comparison, halirutan's `Table` method took 1.183 to complete. RunnyKine's is the fastest I have tested of the others, taking just 0.336 to complete. All times were measured with `AbsoluteTiming`.

Comment: @Uh, I like the use of the new `Composition` operator! Also, I would have gone with `MapIndexed` too but maybe combined it with `Outer`(but I don't have Mathematica to test right now)

Comment: 6 significant digits for the timing results? Is this warranted (even if there is no variation in timing between several runs)?

Comment: @PeterMortensen Thanks for pointing this out; I was mindlessly copying what `AbsoluteTiming` told me, and didn't think about it. I looked through some other posts and they used three decimal numbers, so I updated and did the same.

Comment: Nice use of `@*` -- reasonably short and notably faster than my code. +1 :-)

Answer (score 6):

This is not the shortest, but faster than all except Pickett's (almost just as fast)

```
f4 = Thread@f[#[[1]], #] & /@ Partition[#, Length@#, 1, {1, 1}, {}] &
```

OR

```
 dP = Developer`PartitionMap;
```

Then:

```
f5 = dP[Thread@f[#[[1]], #] &, #, Length@#, 1, {1, 1}, {}] &
```

Timings:

```
Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]

f1 = With[{n = Length[#]}, Table[f @@ #[[{i, j}]], {i, n}, {j, i, n}]] &; 

f2 = MapIndexed[#[[#2[[1]] ;;]] &, Outer[f, #, #]] &;

f3[x_] := Thread@*f @@@ MapIndexed[{#, x[[First@#2 ;;]]} &, x];

BenchmarkPlot[{f1, f2, f3, f4, f5}, RandomInteger[999, #] &, 2^Range[12
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 5):

I don't believe anyone has posted exactly this formulation:

```
MapIndexed[#[[#2[[1]] ;;]] &, Outer[f, #, #]] &
```

Not terribly efficient but the question asked for shortest, not fastest.

---

#### Argument

Although not optimal my method is both *more efficient* and *shorter* than the presently Accepted one.
The question clearly asked for *the shortest way*.  You should not alter your standard after the fact.

**Update:** also including Pickett's code

Please consider:

```
f1 = With[{n = Length[#]}, Table[f @@ #[[{i, j}]], {i, n}, {j, i, n}]] &; 

f2 = MapIndexed[#[[#2[[1]] ;;]] &, Outer[f, #, #]] &;

f3[x_] := Thread@*f @@@ MapIndexed[{#, x[[First@#2 ;;]]} &, x];

Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]

BenchmarkPlot[{f1, f2, f3}, RandomInteger[999, #] &, 2^Range[12]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

A few obfuscations via `Listable`:

```
Block[{f, op},
 SetAttributes[f, Listable];
 op[x_] := {f[x, x]};
 op[x_, y__] := Sequence[f[x, {x, y}], op[y]];
 {op @@ list}
 ]


Block[{f},
 SetAttributes[f, Listable];
 f @@@ Table[{list[[i]], list[[i ;;]]}, {i, 4}]
 ]


Module[{op1, op2},
 op1 = Function[{x, l}, f[x, l], Listable];
 op2 = {op1[#, {##}], Sequence @@ If[{##2} =!= {}, op2[##2], {}]} &;
 op2 @@ list
 ]
```

#### Update

The second method above is actually pretty good. The others aren't bad, but they are limited by `$RecursionLimit`.  This one is slightly faster:

```
f4 = Block[{f},
    SetAttributes[f, Listable];
    f[First[#], #] & /@ NestList[Rest, #, Length[#] - 1]
    ] &;
```

**Timings**

Adding to [Mr.Wizard's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/121/mr-wizard) comparison:

```
f1 = With[{n = Length[#]}, 
    Table[f @@ #[[{i, j}]], {i, n}, {j, i, n}]] &;

f2 = MapIndexed[#[[#2[[1]] ;;]] &, Outer[f, #, #]] &;

f3[x_] := Thread@*f @@@ MapIndexed[{#, x[[First@#2 ;;]]} &, x];

f4 = Block[{f},
    SetAttributes[f, Listable];
    f[First[#], #] & /@ NestList[Rest, #, Length[#] - 1]
    ] &;

Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]

BenchmarkPlot[{f1, f2, f3, f4}, RandomInteger[999, #] &, 2^Range[12]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 4):

A few more just for fun:

```
ReplaceList[list, {___, a__} :> Thread @ f[#& @ a, {a}]]

Thread @* f ~MapThread~ {list, NestList[Rest, list, 3]}

Pick[Outer[f, list, list], # <= #2 & ~Array~ {4, 4}]
```

Answer (score 3):

There is probably something neater but the following works:

```
l = {a, b, c, d};
s = SplitBy[Tuples[l, {2}], First];
list = Take[s[[#]], #2] & @@@ Thread@{Range@Length@l, Range[-Length@l, -1]}
Map[f[Sequence @@ #] &, list, {-2}]
```

> ```
> {{f[a, a], f[a, b], f[a, c], f[a, d]}, {f[b, b], f[b, c], f[b, d]}, 
>  {f[c, c], f[c, d]}, {f[d, d]}}
> ```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a straightforward implementation...

```
Table[Table[f[list[[i]], list[[j]]], {j, i, Length@list}], {i, Length@list}]
```

Here is my flattened table:
If `list` is a sorted list of unique elements

```
list = {a, b, c, d}
g[a_, b_] := f @@ Sort@{a, b};
Union@Flatten@Outer[g, list, list]
```

Comment: My table is flat...

Comment: no the list is not sorted. it is random

Answer (score 3):

```
Thread[f[First@#, #]] & /@ 
 NestList[Drop[#, 1] &, list, Length[list] - 1]
```

The above is a refinement of less efficient 1st attempt:

```
First@Outer[f, #, #] & /@ 
 NestList[Drop[#, 1] &, list, Length[list] - 1]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Outer[f, list, list] /. 
 f[x_, y_] /; 
   First@First@Position[list, x] >  First@First@Position[list, y] :> 
  Sequence[]
```

What's annoying here is projecting `#[[1,1]]&`. How to make `{{1}} <= {{2}}` evaluate `True`?

Answer (score 2):

Building up an `Association`

```
len=Length@list;
asso=<||>;
(asso[#]=list[[-#]])&/@Range@len;
```

and then

```
Array[Function[x,Array[f[x,#]&,x,{x,1}]],len,{len,1}]/.asso
```

Answer (score 2):

Throwing my hat to the ring

```
Clear[splitList]
splitList[f_, list_List] := 
 SplitBy[DeleteDuplicates[Sort /@ Tuples[Sort[Hold[f] @@ list], 2]], First] // ReleaseHold

splitList[f, {a, b, c, d}]
(* {{f[a, a], f[a, b], f[a, c], f[a, d]}, {f[b, b], f[b, c], 
  f[b, d]}, {f[c, c], f[c, d]}, {f[d, d]}} *)

splitList[Plus, {a, b, c, d}]
(* {{2 a, a + b, a + c, a + d}, {2 b, b + c, b + d}, {2 c, c + d}, {2 d}} *)
```

Comment: @RunnyKine I fixed my answer based on your suggestion. Try `splitList[f, {a, b, c, 6, d, 5, b}]` and let me know what you think.

Answer (score 1):

```
f1 = SplitBy[Tuples[f @@ #, 2] /. ( f[x__] /; Not[OrderedQ[{x}]] :> (## &[])), First]& 

f1 @ list // Grid // TeXForm
```

> $\begin{array}{cccc}
>  f(a,a) & f(a,b) & f(a,c) & f(a,d) \\
>  f(b,b) & f(b,c) & f(b,d) & \text{} \\
>  f(c,c) & f(c,d) & \text{} & \text{} \\
>  f(d,d) & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} \\
> \end{array}$

Also

```
f2[l_] := Module[{i = 1, j}, Thread[j = i++; f[l[[j]], l[[j ;;]]]] & /@ l]

f2 @ list == f1 @ list
```

> True