# Tuples which treats re-ordering as equivalent

Tags: list-manipulation, sorting, order, tuples

I would like to define a new function `myTuples`, that behaves just like `Tuples`, except that it treats, as with `Subsets`, re-ordering as equivalent.

As an example output:

```
 n = 3;
 myTuples[{1,2,3},n]
(* Output: {{1,1,1}, {1,1,2}, {1,1,3}, {1,2,2}, {1,2,3}, {1,3,3}, {2,2,2}, {2,2,3},{2,3,3},{3,3,3}} *)
```

It would be possible to achieve this result via the following method:

1. first, apply `Tuples[{1,2,3},n]`
2. then, apply `Sort` on each element
3. then, apply `DeleteDuplicates`

For small $n$, this is ok. However, for larger $n$, the initial list one gets from `Tuples` becomes very large, very quickly (it scales like $3^n$). In parallel, this is going to produce large amounts of duplicates which later are removed, which looks like a waste.
Is there a quicker way to do this?

Alternatively, I was thinking of starting with `Subsets[{1,2,3},n]` instead, and then find a way to add whatever is missing, but this also looks not very straightforward.

Comment: Even after removing duplicates the resulting number of elements in the list becomes very large, very fast.  Maybe if you described what you want to do with the subset of tuples, it might turn out that you don't need to generate all of them in the first place.

Comment: `f[{1, 2, 3}, 3]` from this answer does it: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/42284/4999

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use [`IntegerPartitions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/IntegerPartitions.html).

```
combinations[vec_, n_Integer?Positive] :=
 Flatten[
   IntegerPartitions[#, {n}, Range@Length@vec] & /@ 
    Range[n Length[vec]]
   , 1] /. Thread[Range@Length@vec -> vec]
```

Then

```
combinations[Range@3, 3]
```

> ```
> {{1, 1, 1}, {2, 1, 1}, {3, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 1}, {3, 2, 1}, {2, 2, 2}, {3,3, 1}, {3, 2, 2}, {3, 3, 2}, {3, 3, 3}}
> ```

Works on list of any expression.

```
v = {"x", "y", "z"};
combinations[v, Length@v]
```

> ```
> {{"x", "x", "x"}, {"y", "x", "x"}, {"z", "x", "x"}, {"y", "y", "x"}, {"z", "y", "x"}
>  , {"y", "y", "y"}, {"z", "z", "x"}, {"z", "y", "y"}, {"z", "z", "y"}, {"z", "z", "z"}}
> ```

Works for large list and `n`.  Note current version of @BobHanlon `myTuples` will fail on insufficient memory error for `RepeatedTiming[myTuples[Range@10, 10];]` on my 128GB RAM laptop.

```
RepeatedTiming[combinations[Range@10, 10];]
```

> ```
> {0.269681, Null}
> ```

Also for `n` greater than or less then the length of the list.

```
combinations[Range@3, 2]
```

and

```
combinations[Range@3, 5]
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by counting using nested Tables functions. Unfortunately, it gets pretty complicated for arbitrary number of elements because we need to create the `Table` commands by code.

For an example we take a list of n==3 elements:

```
n = 3;
d = Range[n];
```

The number of iterators needed depends on n. This makes it a bit complicated to generate programmatically the iterators in the Table command we are going to construct. The first iterator runs from 0 to n. The  iterators without the last one are created by:

```
iters = Join[{{i1, 0, n}}, 
   Table[{Symbol["i" <> ToString[i]], 0, 
     n - Sum[Symbol["i" <> ToString[j]], {j, i - 1}]}, {i, 2, 
     n - 1}] ];
```

The body of our table is given by:

```
body := Table[
   Table[d[[i]], {Symbol["i" <> ToString[i]]}], {i, n - 1}];
```

To write the table, we need to insert the iterators using `Evaluate` because `Table` has the attribute HoldAll. The different table commands create too many levels of nesting, that we need to eliminate using `Flatten`. And to get the sublists in ascending order we finally apply `Reverse`:

```
    Flatten /@  Flatten[
Table[ Join[dat, Table[d[[n]], {n - Sum[Symbol["i" <> ToString[j]], {j, n - 1}]}]]
, Evaluate[Sequence @@ iters]]
, 1] // Reverse
```

For our example, we get the result:

[image]